# How to build a query object for Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I am building an iOS app using Swift.
I am using Realm as database.

I am currently building a search functionality for a tableview.

This is my filter query

```
items = realm.objects(Book).filter(predicate).filter("state IN {'pending','activated','completed','closed'}")
```

I am saving what states a user wants to filter on in another model called Filter.

How can I build this {'pending','activated','completed','closed'} from the output of the following filter query (title is the attribute)? What is this object called?

```
realm.objects(Filter).filter("type = 'filter' AND activated = 'true'")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right-hand side of the `IN` operator can take a substitution placeholder (`%@`) that can have an `NSArray` (or other enumerable object) substituted in.

Assuming your `Filter` model looks something like:

```
class Filter: Object {
    dynamic var type: String = ""
    dynamic var activated: bool = false
    dynamic var state: String = ""
}
```

You can do something like the following to construct the query you're after:

```
let activeFilters = realm.objects(Filter).filter("type = 'filter' AND activated = 'true'")
let activeStates = activeFilters.valueForKey("state") as! [String]!

let items = realm.objects(Book).filter(predicate).filter("state IN %@", activeStates)
```